# How to change initial data when 'new insert' or when 'alter data'

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am making form like this doneAt is date time table.

```
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $d = new \DateTime;
    $formMapper
        ->with('General')
        ->with('name')
        ->add('doneAt',null,array('data' => $d))
        ->add('enabled',null, array('required' => false))
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

'doneAt form' always set to currenttime as initial data.

But I would not like to set initial data when data is already stored.

for example

1) make new data
doneAt shows 2014/04/17 (today), so I changed this data to 2014/03/03 and save

2) alter exsting data
then I clicked the data inserted by 1) but, doneAt is set current time(not 2013/03/03 but 2014/04/17).
I would like to keep initial data as 2013/03/03

In summary what I want to do is

```
if (doneAt is stored)
        ->add('doneAt')

if (doneAt is not stored)
        ->add('doneAt',null,array('data' => $d))
```

how can I make it ?

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to use [Doctrine Extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html) for this purpose.

I think that you may use [timestampable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md) extension for your goals.

For example - field $updated will by set on Update only:

```
 /**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $updated;
```

Field $created will store current timestamp only in new object

```
 /**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;
```

You can also tracks property or a list of properties for changes(title and body), like this:

```
 /**
 * @var datetime $contentChanged
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content_changed", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="change", field={"title", "body"})
 */
private $contentChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

If doneAt is required you can simply set defaut value in entity class:

```
$doneAt = new \DateTime();
```

This sets default value in entity allways if its not set.
You can also check in your Admin newly created entity:

```
if($this->subject->getId()){ // new entity has not id set
```